# Ribbon using CSS for tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am creating a ribbon on a table but facing some issues. 
I am not able make the ribbon on the table. Some how it looks very odd.

```css
.sash {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
}
.sash:after {
  content: "Sash";
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(49deg);
}
```

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black" class="sash">
  <tr>
    <td>one line text</td>
    <td>two line text</td>
    <td>three line text</td>
    <td>four line text</td>
    <td width="100"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>one line text</td>
    <td>two line text</td>
    <td>three line text</td>
    <td>four line text</td>
    <td width="100"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly is the desired visual effect you're going for?

Comment: Same as what  http://www.cssportal.com/blog/create-corner-ribbon/  but using Table structure.

Is there any alternative way to avoid Pseudo classes like before , after ?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

```css
.sash {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
}
.sash:after {
  content: attr(data-ribbon);
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  right: -27px;
  transform: rotate(49deg);
}
```

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black" class="sash" data-ribbon="Sach">
  <tr>
    <td>one line text</td>
    <td>two line text</td>
    <td>three line text</td>
    <td>four line text</td>
    <td width="100"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>one line text</td>
    <td>two line text</td>
    <td>three line text</td>
    <td>four line text</td>
    <td width="100"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For each row:

```css
.sash tr td:last-child {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
}
.sash tr td:last-child:after {
  content: attr(data-ribbon);
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  right: -12px;
  transform: rotate(49deg);
}
```

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black" class="sash">
  <tr>
    <td>one line text</td>
    <td>two line text</td>
    <td>three line text</td>
    <td>four line text</td>
    <td width="100" data-ribbon="One"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>one line text</td>
    <td>two line text</td>
    <td>three line text</td>
    <td>four line text</td>
    <td width="100" data-ribbon="Two"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you ! is  there any alternative that I can avoid pseudo classes ? as My value for sash is going to be dynamic.

Comment: @user769456 Yes, using a _clever_ pseudo ... I will update the answer in a sec.

Comment: @user769456 Updated using `data-ribbon` attribute and CSS `attr()`

Comment: My bad. The sash would be appearing for each row. So will have to redefine structure for each row.

Comment: @user769456 Added a sample to the answer how that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

that one is a little bit pretty :)

```css
 
.sash tr td{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  
}
.sash tr td.prova:after {
  content: attr(data-ribbon);
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #428bca;
  color: white;
  top: -5px;
  text-align: center ;
  line-height: 50px;
  right: -34px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black" class="sash">
  <tr>
    <td>one line text</td>
    <td>two line text</td>
    <td>three line text</td>
    <td>four line text</td>
    <td class="prova" data-ribbon="★">hhgfghg</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>one line text</td>
    <td>two line text</td>
    <td>three line text</td>
    <td >fouer line text</td>
    <td class="prova" data-ribbon="★"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```